# Android: Count interval of MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: android, intervals, touch-event, translate-animation

I want my Views to move horizontally in tandem with our finger moving. Please imagine something like iOS home menu or Photos (the pre-installed galley app); if you slide your forefinger, the stuff on the screen also slide. I couldn't find the same function in Android libraries, so I just implemented it myself, but...

The animation isn't that smooth!

That's understandable, since the location values I get by

```
event.getRawX();
```

are a bit too rough, so my TranslateAnimation is also rough...

Is there any way I can change the interval of MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE to get more fine location values? (Or alternatively, could I "blur" my TranslateAnimation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) may be what you are looking for.

Also see the Developers blog entry [Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Comment: Thanks. I made a quick research on it and it seems to require some extra works to learn about it. With ViewPager, when I stop flicking halfway and leave my finger, the view automatically returns to the original position? (like the one on iOS)

Comment: Yes, it does. Check out the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) sample app on Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample